# how to build a map from logged data

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get a 2d map. I am following the slam_gmapping tutorial [MappingFromLoggedData](http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData).

I get the bag, and I do rosmake gmapping and roscore
after I did rscore, I brought up the master.
my question is what should I do next...
should I start a new terminal, and then do rosparam set use_sim_time true  or something else? when I am in the master, I enter some commands, but it does not respond to me...
I am trying to skip this two steps, and go directly to the rosbag play  I run the rosbag and it is done. I am tring to get the map, so I ran rosrun map_server map_saver, but it is an error: [rospack] Error: stack/package map_server not found

can anyone tells me how to deal with that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59878/how-to-build-a-map-from-logged-data/) by [unknown](https://answers.ros.org/users/4599/unknown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install map_server before you can execute a script inside of it.  Or you need to make sure it's on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1